# Magento 2.2.x 500 internal server error upon installation

Tags: magento2, htaccess

I have just installed magento 2.2.4 on my cPanel and I got internal server error 500. I tried to rename .htaccess file but then it opens with no css and its admin gives 404 error. My cPanel uses PHP 7.1 and mysql 5.6

Comment: Error 500 means that you are getting a fatal error. Did you check your apache logs? The error should be there.

Comment: I have a cpanel based VPS hosting with ssh access. Can you please tell me how to check apache logs?

Comment: Try logging into your SSH and typing cd /var/log/apache2 The error log should be there. It is usually named error.log, but can be named differently, depending on your virtual host configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the solution given in this [install Apache module](https://blog.hunzathreadz.com/500-internal-server-error/)

I too faced the same problem , but I was able to fix it by installing the required Apache module

Answer (score 0):

This php version problem. please use 7.0.2 version